# STTwitter swift type 'Any' has no subscript members on getHomeTimeline method

Tags: ios, swift, sttwitter

All, I am really new to iOS development so that means I am new to Swift. I have knowledge of other programming languages like c#, PHP, Node JS, etc. However, I have found myself stuck and can't find any answers.

I am working with STTwitter and I am trying to pull the status of my Twitter. I can pull it fine using the normal method. When I try to add a loop, I get an error: Type 'Any' has no subscript members.

```
// Verifying Twitter API creds
    twitter?.verifyCredentials(userSuccessBlock: { (username, userId) in

        // Get Twitter Timeline Status
        twitter?.getHomeTimeline(sinceID: nil, count: 10, successBlock: { (statuses) -> Void in

            for status in statuses! {
                print(status["text"])
            }

        }, errorBlock: { (error) in
            print(error)
        })

        print(username, userId)
    }, errorBlock: { (error) in
        print(error)
    })
```

[Here is a screenshot of the actual editor with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwzxJ.png)

The error is on the "status" inside the print statement inside the for loop.

Any help would be great!

Comment: It seems that this library is written in Objective-C, and `getHomeTimeline` accepts a "block" which is passed an `NSArray *`, which translates in Swift into `[Any]`, so you must translate this `Any`, to the datatype really existing. If you are sure it is a dictionary, do this: `(status as? NSDictionary)?["text"]`

Comment: OMG That worked!!! Thank you so much @user9335240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getHomeTimeline` accepts a "block" (or Swift closure) that is passed an `NSArray *`, which is translated in Swift to [Any]. So

```
    // Get Twitter Timeline Status
    twitter?.getHomeTimeline(sinceID: nil, count: 10, successBlock: { (statuses) -> Void in

        for status in statuses! {
            print((status as? NSDictionary)?["text"])
        }

    }
```